# How to find a $f(x)$ on a interval $[a,b]$ such that $\int_a^b f(x) dx = \lim_n u_n$, for a series $u_n$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis

I'm asked to find the limit of $u_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i}{n^2}$ **using a Riemann sum**, and even though I find the correct answer, I'm not sure my reasoning is valid or well-funded. First I define

1. $\sigma_k\in\Delta_{1,n}$ be a segment of the closed interval $[1,n]$, i.e. a set $\sigma_k = \{x_k\}_{k\in K \subset \mathbb{N}}$ such that $x_k\in [1,n]$ for all $k$.
2. $\delta_n = \frac{n-1}{n}$
3. $f_n:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}:x\mapsto\frac{x}{n(n-1)}$

Given this, I think I can build a Riemann sum $R(f_n,\sigma_k) = \sum_i^n f_n(x_i)\delta_n$ for all $x_i \in \sigma_k$, and actually $R(f_n,\sigma_k) = u_n$. If this is the case, we should have $\lim_{n\to\infty} u_n = \lim_n R(f_n,\sigma_k) = \int_1^n f(x)dx$ but, surprisingly,

$$\lim_n u_n = \lim_n (\lim_n R(f_n,\sigma_k)) = \lim_n \int_1^n \frac{x}{n(n-1)} dx = \frac{1}{2}$$

This double limit is pretty awkward and therefore I assume I'm wrong in my reasoning. Moreover, I've noticed that

$$\lim u_n = \lim_n \int_1^n \frac{x}{n^2} dx = \frac{1}{2}$$

which works, even though I don't know why.

EDIT:
After reading the comments, I thought of a better way to put my question.
**What criteria or intuition should one follow to find a function $f(x)$ on a interval $[a,b]$ such that $\int_a^b f(x) dx = \lim_n u_n$, for a series $u_n$?**

Comment: You can factor $n$ outside of the summation giving $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{i}{n^2} = \frac{1}{n^2}\cdot \sum\limits_{i=1}^n i = \frac{1}{n^2}\cdot \frac{n(n+1)}{2} = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2n}$

Comment: The idea is to solve the limit through a Riemann sum.

Comment: You're making this too difficult. The sums are Riemann sums for $f(x)=x$ 0n $[0,1].$ The limit is $\int_0^1 x\,dx = 1/2.$